# Props values changes when clicked onpress within a Flatlist item

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Props values gets changed onpress() event of FlatList Item. I am passing an array but the array gets auto nested again into an array causing issues on Second time onpress event of the same item.

Below is the first time onpress data:

```
Object {
  "content": "Data",
  "date": "2022-06-04",
  "image": "url",
  "link": "url",
  "pubdate": "2022-06-04T20:00:33.639242+05:30",
  "source": "abc",
  "time": "20:00:33",
  "title": "abc",
}
```

Below is the Second time onpress Data:

```
Object {
"item":Object {
  "content": "Data",
  "date": "2022-06-04",
  "image": "url",
  "link": "url",
  "pubdate": "2022-06-04T20:00:33.639242+05:30",
  "source": "abc",
  "time": "20:00:33",
  "title": "abc",
},
}
```

Below is the FlatList View which has the onpress event:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { StyleSheet, View, Dimensions, Text, Modal, Share } from "react-native";
import { Icon, Tile } from "react-native-elements";
import {
  Avatar,
  Button,
  Card,
  Title,
  Paragraph,
  Subheading,
  Caption,
} from "react-native-paper";
import moment from "moment";
import { WebView } from "react-native-webview";
import { ActivityIndicator } from "react-native";
import { MaterialCommunityIcons } from "@expo/vector-icons";

// import { Container } from './styles';

const { width } = Dimensions.get("window");
const { webViewHeight } = Dimensions.get("window").height - 56;

const BlockCard = ({ navigation, item }) => {
  const { image, title, source, date, time, link } = item;
  const momentsago = moment(date + " " + time, "YYYY/MM/DD HH:mm:ss").fromNow();
  const source2 = source + " | " + momentsago;
  return (
    <View style={styles.centeredView}>
      <Card>
        <Card.Cover source={{ uri: image }} />
        <Card.Content>
          {/* <Subheading style={{fontWeight:"bold"}}>{title}</Subheading> */}
          <Title>{title}</Title>
          <Caption style={{ fontWeight: "bold" }}>{source2}</Caption>
        </Card.Content>
        <Card.Actions style={{ alignSelf: "flex-end" }}>
          <Button icon="share-variant" color="#E1B72E">
            Share
          </Button>
          <Button
            icon="open-in-new"
            color="#E1B72E"
            onPress={() => navigation.navigate("Details", (item = { item }))}
          >
            Explore
          </Button>
        </Card.Actions>
      </Card>
    </View>
  );
};
```

Below is the Details Screen:

```
const Details = ({ navigation, route }) => {
  var { image, title, source, date, time, link, pubdate, content } =
    route.params.item;
  var momentsago = moment(date + " " + time, "YYYY/MM/DD HH:mm:ss").fromNow();
  var source2 = source + " | " + momentsago;

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(route.params.item);
  });
```

The Console.log captured the variance in the Data. Kindly provide me any pointers as I am very new to React Native.

Comment: I don't see any `FlatList` there?

Comment: My Bad, Its called via another Screen. The Card is the FlatList item show above. Cards are populated well. From Card I pass on to Details screen which is causing the error. every second time I click the same card I do not see the Details Screen values because of the incorrect array in route.params.items passed by props item

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the nesting occurs here:

```js
 <Button
            icon="open-in-new"
            color="#E1B72E"
            onPress={() => navigation.navigate("Details", (item = { item }))}
          >
            Explore
          </Button>
```

Try doing this instead

```js
 <Button
            icon="open-in-new"
            color="#E1B72E"
            onPress={() => navigation.navigate("Details",item)}
          >
            Explore
          </Button>
```